# Can't control case fan speeds

Tags: speed, fan, case

I a new case fan that is plugged directly in to the Mobo in "System Fan 2".  I want to be able to control the RPMs of the fan. I have enabled system fan control in the bios. I am using SpeedFan. I am changing the % of Speed03 (Which is the only one that shows the RPMs since its the only one connected to the board) However nothing happens. Are there some setting in SpeedFan I need to set? Where do you think the problem lays?

The Case fan is XIGMATEK XLF-F1253
The Mobo is Gigabyte MA770-UD3 Rev1

Let me know your opinion. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Speedfan is unable to control the fan speeds of my case fans connected to a Gigabyte GA-EP35-DS3L motherboard. The mobo does not have the correct hardware (PWM fan controllers?). You may be running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Speedfan can be quite a PITA to configure. However I managed to get it working following [this](http://www.gadgetbuilder.com/Computer/SpeedFanInfo.html) guide.

Answer (score 0):

You may ultimately need a hardware fan controller, at least for some of the fans. This was the case for my Gigabyte motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

The key part in speedfan is setting your motherboard PWM fans to  "Software controlled" (now called Manual I noticed) in Options for your chipset, then try to increase or decrease various speeds until you find one that affects your fan (you'll probably find one for your CPU too). Don't forget to untick "Automatic" on the main screen other the arrows do nothing!

Do *not* assume that numbers match and that Speed03 is your fan, maybe it's your cpu fan showing? Set them all to manual and try them one by one. On my board, the cpu fan is shown as case fan, somewhow.

Do *not* assume that your motherboard supports fan control on all your fans. Some board circuitry only support control for the cpu fan, some on cpu + one other fan only. Rarely are all fans controllable. Check your manual (or google) for PWM support. Try other fan ports. Try disabling any fan option in BIOS (use the "always on", "max", "not intelligent" or similar option)

Do *not* worry about speeds. Put your case on the table and look inside while doing this. Some fans do not report speed properly, but can still be controlled. Speedfan sets speed according to temperature, so you don't even really need to read the RPM. You just have to find the % at which your fan stops working by looking at it.

Check that your fan supports PWM, too. Some don't. Most do.

That said, Speedfan rocks.